# Visual State Transition not applied when DataTemplate is applied via Content Control

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

Depending on how my buttons Control Template is set, the Visual States will or won't be applied. Unfortunately the mechanism by which I see them working isn't available to me as it isn't dynamic enough.

Hooking up the datatemplate via a content control and binding does render the Textblocks Content fine, it just doesn't handle the transition when the button is disabled

```
<Style x:Key="ItemsControlStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="xxx:myType">
                <Button Command="{Binding ActionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item}" Height="125" Width="200" Margin="10" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{Binding ItemDataTemplateKey, Converter={StaticResource StringToDataTemplateConverter}}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>


<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="Textblock" Text="{Binding Caption}" FontFamily="{DynamicResource DefaultFont}"/>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:0.01"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I hook up the template inline everything works as expected

```
<Style x:Key="ItemsControlStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="xxx:myType">
                <Button Command="{Binding ActionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item}" Height="125" Width="200" Margin="10" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" >
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="{Binding Caption}" FontFamily="{DynamicResource DefaultFont}"/>

                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:0.01"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: `ContentTemplate="ItemTemplate"` is wrong. `"ItemTemplate"` is a string, not a datatemplate. `ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"` should work, after you move the DataTemplate above the Style, so it's defined before you reference it.

Comment: Sorry in my attempt to simplify the xaml for this post I took out some things which were important. In reality i'm using a converter to return me the datatemplate. The template is definitely getting picked up, as i said the TextBlocks content renders fine.

Comment: I came here with the same problem in my own code; there's definitely an issue with DataTemplates in ContentControls.